# Loading an external module into a signed kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, boot-loader, signature

The steam link is running a valve signed Linux kernel, however the sdk provided by valve states that attempting to replace theirs with an unsigned binary will render the device unbootable.

Would this signing prevent loading external kernel modules, and cause it to no longer boot?

Comment: I would rather not brick it.